# Strange output in simple function - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simple function in Excel VBA.

```
Public Function ubi() As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 7 To 10
       If IsNumeric(Cells(35, i).Value) Then
           ubi = i
       End If
   Next

   ubi = i

End Function
```

As you see, the values of `i` are supposed to be `7` or `8` or `9` or `10`. But, when I test the function in the Excel Worksheet I find `ubi()=11`.

So, What could be the source of error in my code ?

Comment: Try removing the `ubi = i` outside of the `For...Next` loop?

Comment: Also, you are calling up a function with no conditions in the function?

Comment: With your advice I see the error is fixed. However I still don´t know why ubi()=11 appears in the former code.

Comment: Yes, I call up the function just to check the values of certain cells.

Comment: The code keeps going while this is true: `For i = 7 To 10`  Every time you hit this `Next` is is incremented.  When i gets incremented to 11, the loop exits - but i is already set to 11.

Comment: Is your Cell Values always in G35:J35?  Based on your code these are the only 4 cells that will ever be checked.  And, if G35, I35, and J35 are all numeric, it will return 10 although you have 3 of them as numeric.

Comment: Yes, It will always be based on G35:J35

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine?  Do you want to find how many of the cells are numeric?

Comment: I just wanted to find the last cell of the range with numeric values!

Comment: Ok that works... Making it more complicated then necessary.

Comment: If you have a simpler code it would be good to see your code!.

Comment: No I was going to make it more complicated by having it tell you how many of the four where numeric.  `ubi = 0` before the loop and `ubi = ubi + 1` instead of `ubi = i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `ubi = i` from outside the `For...Next` loop
The code keeps going while this is true: `For i = 7 To 10` Every time you hit this `Next` it is incremental. When i gets increased to 11, the loop exits - but i is already set to 11.

Comment: With your advice I see the error is fixed. However I still don´t know why ubi()=11 appears in the former code.

Comment: @CreamStat because the variable _i_ increases until 11, that's the reason why the For Loop is stopped ;)

Comment: I was just going to say that... The "Next" command goes to the next step (11 in this case).

Comment: @Chrismas007 Add it to your answer to make it complete. CreamStat don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: It was what I suspected. Thanks!